# $_SESSION failing when calling PHP file through a CDN

Tags: php, regex, session, cdn

I am not sure if using a CDN is appropriate here in the first place. The content I am hosting is an Apache(with PHP + MySQL) backend for a mobile application.

Instead of calling my PHP files through example.com/test.php, I am accessing them through Amazon's CloudFront CDN with a url of the form

RAND_ALPHA_NUMERIC.cloudfront.net/test.php

I noticed that calling the PHP file as such prevents the $_SESSION variable from properly working.

Anything I'm missing here? Is my approach all by itself flawed?

Thanks.

Comment: depends on your session cookie settings, and yes, it's probably flawed. since the site name is random, you'd have to set your cookie for `.cloudfrount.net`, which'd make the cookie global for ALL sites front by cloudfront.

Comment: What would be the approach you'd recommend? @MarcB

Comment: @MarcB is correct, since php uses a cookie to get the session id and grab the data in localstorage (not in database) on the server. make sure your cookie settings allow all subdomains and that the timezones between all the CDN servers evaluate to the same timezone, if you have cookies set to expire in 2 hours, if it hits NY first then if they hit a server in London right after, the cookie will expire

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

Comment: @iam-decoder I have set the session cookie to expire after 24 hours but didn't solve the issue yet.

Comment: @JosephK then it's most likely the subdomain problem. look at the docs that remus commented